# Casting interface can reflecting on array types

Tags: go

The code below is an adaption of a Python script. Of course, it doesn't compile and there are a couple of reasons for this.

I am struggling to understand how it's possible to fix it so it gives the right result.

In particular:

1. I want to represent either a type (`float64`) or an `array` of this type so I am naively using an `[]interface` but then passing an array won't work. I understand I could deep copy an interface array with my array but is it the only way?
2. The reflection check works (kinda) but then I am back to casting an interface to an `[]interface` and that doesn't work.
3. A simpler way would be to pass `[]float` but I also want to make the code generic (oops! ;-) enough to accept `[][]floats` and recursively descend with the comparisons.

Am I completely offtrack?

```
func assertArrayEquals(first []interface{}, second []interface{}) bool {
    if len(first) != len(second) {
        return false
    }
    for i := range first {
        if reflect.ValueOf(first[i]).Kind() == reflect.Array {
            assertArrayEquals([]interface{}(first[i]), []interface{}(second[i]))
        } else if second[i] != first[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    assertArrayEquals([]float64{[]float64{0, 1}, []float64{0, 1}}, []float64{[]float64{0, 1}, []float64{0, 1}})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to implement assertArrayEquals:

```
func assertArrayEquals(first interface{}, second interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.DeepEqual(first, second)
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/XPSVPUeaq4)

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed that function.